# Can I use regex to match a predefined string in java?

Tags: java, regex

I am quite new to regex and java, I am trying to make an AI to play hangman.

I have an list of a lot of words, When a user guesses a letter I build the string to show that.  When the user guesses the letter I want to refine the list to only contain words that have letters in the positions that I have guessed correct.

So lets say the word is 'cat'. I start with a string "..." when user guesses an 'a' I update the string to '.a.'

How can I use regex to remove all of the strings in the array that doesnt follow this pattern? Can I use regex for this?  Any help is greatly appreciated and thank you.

Comment: _"..to remove all of the strings in the array"_ What strings and what array? Please be specific. Moreover, [If your question doesn't include code, are you sure it shouldn't?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/4934172)

Answer (score 0):

To "remove" all strings from the array that don't match, You would use the regex `.a.+` or `.+[aA].+` to test all the words in the array for a regex match and build up a new/replacement array with only the words matching the regex.

- `.a.+` will match all words three letters or longer with `a` in the second position
- `.[aA].+` will match all words three letters or longer with `a` or `A` in the second position.
- Both of these regex will also match non word strings with `a` (or `A`) in the second position - but if you know the pool of words that will be tested (the words in your array) don't contain any non-word characters, then simple matching on the "any character" dot operator is much easier to implement than covering all the non-word edge cases properly

These are some decent regex learning resources:

- https://www.regular-expressions.info/index.html
- https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html

I've found that unit tests are a great place to "experiment" with various regex pattern strings and input strings to fine tune the actual application behavior you seek.

Comment: I don't think the `+`es are necessary for a hangman game.  Unless it's a very strange variant of hangman, typically the guessing player will know the length of the word.

Comment: Maybe not, but I figured the "array of words" represents the "universe" of all possible words and the player does not know how many letters the hidden word has.  Thus when the word is 'cat' and the player has guessed 'a'  the universe of all possible words in this round shrinks to only those words (in the universe) with 'a' in the second position.